# Converting <unicode> to str after serialization and using smart_text() in django

Tags: python, django, unicode

For some reason, the smart_text() utility is not converting the unicode into the string.

I have data that is serialized and looks like:

```
{u'text': u'alskdfkld', u'chatroom': OrderedDict([(u'id', 18), ('created_at', u'2016-01-13T18:41:26.517572Z'), ('creator', 29), ('participant', 33)]), u'written_at': u'2016-01-13T19:27:49.118914Z', u'author': OrderedDict([(u'id', 29), ('password', u'pbkdf2_sha256$24000$h0whlzx0BleT$4cUWdRkUsPYB7Ia6F+pYxX+31BMhJJfpWiLHfoL9NOY='), ('last_login', u'2016-01-12T21:06:40.574122Z'), ('email', u'superman@gmail.com'), ('username', u'superman'), ('first_name', u'clark'), ('last_name', u'kent'), ('is_active', True), ('is_admin', False), ('joined_on', u'2016-01-06T23:57:43.191484Z'), ('is_online', True), ('is_contractor', False), ('profile_pic', '/media/bicycle_z3NDBPI.jpeg'), ('rating', None), ('address', u''), ('braintree_id', u'20401140'), ('socket_id', u'awnxF65jy2suqNRHAAAE'), ('subcategory', None)])}
```

And then I passed it through smart_text() like so:

```
context = smart_text(context, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict')
```

The output looks exactly the same.

Should I be using some other utility to do this conversion?

Comment: This is a Python dict. smart_text will not do anything with it. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to pass it through Redis channel which pings the socket, and then on the html side, json parse so that I can access the values in the object.

Comment: Then you should probably try to convert it to JSON.